minimum atmospheric nitrogen for nitrogen fixation?
what is the minimum partial pressure of atmospheric nitrogen for nitrogen fixing bacteria to actually convert nitrogen into usable forms like ammonia? currently writing history for life within a 120 kPa atmosphere with a composition of 76% argon, 16% oxygen, 7% nitrogen, and 0.04% carbon dioxide and other trace gases. i've been writing under the assumption that soil would generally be extremely deprived of nitrogen because of this atmosphere, leading to the development of peat-based fertilizers to help soil sustain agriculture. but i read somewhere (can't remember where) that nitrogen fixing bacteria can work with partial pressures as low as 10-20 kPa. so i'm thinking that nitrogen fixation would still be relatively inefficient in my world, but probably not as much as i initially thought. anyone know?

I know this isn't what you asked for but with an atmosphere of 76% argon I would think that something would have evolved to make use of that. While the noble gasses are generally not reactive, there are argon compounds https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_gas_compound#Argon_compounds that have been discovered. There would likely be an evolutionary advantage to making use of the most abundant element in the atmosphere, so it's not impossible that evolution on your planet would have resulted in at least some argon using life forms.

@penguinaut reading that, it takes fluorine (the strongest possible oxidant) to do something with them noble gasses, and fluorine would likely drop off those argon compounds in presense of literally anything else, as connection strength of F vs everything is quite high. I don't think argon compounds would be stable out of lab, regardless of environment.

It seems reasonable to assume that nitrogen fixation would continue at lower partial pressures of nitrogen, but might simply occur at a lower rate.
All other things being equal (which they probably aren’t but…) The partial pressure of nitrogen gas might be expected to be proportional to the rate of reaction at constant temperature and pressure:
https://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/basicrates/pressure.html
But if the rate limiting step is the reaction between the nitrogen and hydrogen on the surface of the nitrogenase enzyme (rather than the diffusion of nitrogen onto the surface), then nitrogen pressure might not have much effect (at least at modest pressure reductions).
If the rate limiting step is the diffusion of the nitrogen onto the surface of the nitrogenase enzyme (rather than the speed of reaction on the surface) then the reduction in nitrogen pressure should be proportional to the rate of reaction.
So worst case the rate of reaction should be proportional to the nitrogen partial pressure. But if it takes the enzyme a long time to react the nitrogen and hydrogen then it may be possible to have the same rate of reaction with reduced pressure (down to some lower pressure limit).
